# The below code validated only index 0 I want to check n number of index of array what need to be included

Tags: javascript

The for loop i = 0 checks the password only 0th index I want to check for all index what need to be included.

```
function validlogin() {
      var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
      var psw = document.getElementById('psw').value;
    
      var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'));
    
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    
        if (items[i].username == user && items[i].password == psw)
          {
    
          alert("welcome");
          
          
          }
         
    }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find` to discover the user with the matching username and then validate their password. It looks like you're managing logins on the client-side, definitely don't do this for a production application.

Assuming the `login` localStorage object looks like `[{username: "Among Us", password: "Red is sus"}]`, here's how you'd do it:

```js
function validlogin() {
    const user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    const psw = document.getElementById('psw').value;
    
    const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'));

    const userData = items.find(({username}) => username === user);

    if (!userData) {
        alert('No user found');
        return;
    }

    if (userData.password !== psw) {
        alert('Incorrect password');
        return;
    }

    alert(`Logged in as ${userData.username}`);
}
```

Comment: Hi Richie , Thankyou man Its working another think If he login successfully he need to be redirected to a page were he need to view his status which  is in local storage. Example 0: {email: "kalaiarasu@gmail.com", username: "CIVILvQTUJ2111", password: "8sRiMuvCPqxC",…}
email: "kalaiarasu@gmail.com"
password: "8sRiMuvCPqxC"
status: "marksheets are evaluating"
username: "CIVILvQTUJ2111"

Comment: A client-server model would have the server provide the client with an authentication token which they can use to pull data from the server. To do this locally for fun, you could use `sessionStorage` to store the authenticated username then redirect to another page and load it from there. If you found my original answer useful, be sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something using this logic:

```
function validlogin() {
  var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
  var psw = document.getElementById('psw').value;

  var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'));

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    if (items.username.join('') == user && items.password.join('') == psw)
      {

      alert("welcome");
      
      
      }
     
}
  }
```

Comment: 0: {email: "kalaiarasu@gmail.com", username: "CIVILvQTUJ2111", password: "8sRiMuvCPqxC",…}
email: "kalaiarasu@gmail.com"
password: "8sRiMuvCPqxC"
status: "marksheets are evaluating"
username: "CIVILvQTUJ2111"
1: {email: "Ramanathan@gmail.com", username: "CIVILaTvSg7030", password: "Kgpu1TxYJ4iv"}
email: "Ramanathan@gmail.com"
password: "Kgpu1TxYJ4iv"
username: "CIVILaTvSg7030"
2: {email: "ramesh@gmail.com", username: "CIVILAnpGG3733", password: "TofUmX6XBHNj"}
email: "ramesh@gmail.com"
password: "TofUmX6XBHNj"
username: "CIVILAnpGG3733"

Comment: This is the data I need to validate which is stored in local storage key named login in for(i = 0) its validating but if credential is not matched it need to check next 1 after 0 index and so on which is not taking place.